# Export to excel with images in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I have the following code :

```
<button id="myButtonControlID" onclick="ExcelExport();">Export to Excel</button>
<script>
function ExcelExport(){
var imgurl = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/60/60752.svg"
var HTMLtext="<table><tr><td>Image export</td><td><img src='"+imgurl+"'style='width:500px;height:600px;'></img></td></tr></table>";
window.location.href = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(HTMLtext);
sa = window.location.href;
     return (sa);
}
</script>
```

With this I am able to export an excel file as XLS but since the image is a link,it is only displayed when I am connected to the internet. Is there a way to embed the image to excel in such a way that the image is not a link and it is displayed even when you are offline?

Comment: I am the developer of an Export to Excel library. I am interested in this too. Take a look here: https://github.com/jmaister/excellentexport/